# Request data from HTML paragraph to download using Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I know that `<p>` is a display element. Therefore, I am displaying data inside the paragraph as a python variable in the `<body>`

```
 <p>
        {{ filename }}
 </p>
```

But In the `<header>` I have a download button that downloads whatever in the `<p>` as a text file.

To do that I stored another version of the data in a hidden `<input>` Then I put a download button as follows:

```
<input method="post" type="hidden" name="fileData" value="{{ filename }}" />

<a  href="{{ url_for('download_file') }}">Download</a>
```

In Flask I have this:

```
@app.route('/database_download', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request['fileData']
        response = make_response(f)
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.txt"
        return response
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

The problem I have is that when I remove `return render_template` from the end, it gives me a `ValueError: View function did not return a response` or if I keep it then when I click on download nothing happens, it just re-direct me to the same page. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requests must be GETs, because you're not passing the

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

line, and so getting the responses you described.

Get out your debugger, and figure out what the value of request.method is, and then go from there.

Or, you can double check that you're sending POST requests in your client-side code.

Comment: you are right! I print the result in the console and it is 'Get'. I am not sure how to pass 'Post' since I already wrote 'method=post' in the input field and added it to the 'download' button as well. I also have if-statement to check if it is 'post' in Flask. Would please give me a hint or any suggestions on how to fix it! Appreciate that man!

Comment: You can try formmethod="post" in your input element. Input elements are made to work within form elements, though, and usually use those forms to submit. Research forms and use that. It's a simple way to get data back and forth.